# White Space under footer and right side of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see on this website (http://jonydeloser.fcdesperados.be/pages/index.aspx) I am having a white space at the right side & beneath my footer.

Anyone got an idea what the problem might be?

Already tried a lot of things, none worked...

Note: I am working with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light-theme.css line 2214 change the styles to this:

```
#footer .footer-wrapper {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
}
```

The current padding is applied to top and bottom and is pushing out the bottom of the page.

EDIT - OK take out this code, it was a bit hacky anyway:

```
#footer {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Then go to line 584 of bootstrap.css and remove `margin-right: -15px;` that should fix your right side white bar issue everywhere.

Comment: I also tried the overflow-x:hidden on my body. It fixes it on my pc, but on my smartphone you can still scroll and see the white space...

The padding worked worked out perfectly thanks!